# Why am I getting a symbol lookup error?

Tags: c++

I am writing a library, which is dynamically loaded in my main-application with dlsym.
I have the following files:

library.h

```
#include <ilibrary.h>
#include <igateway.h>

class LibraryImpl;

class Library: public ILibrary {
public:
    static ILibrary* instance();

    IGateway* getGateway() const;

protected:
    Library();
    virtual ~Library();

private:
    static ILibrary* instance_;
    LibraryImpl* library_;
};

extern "C" {
    IMPORT_EXPORT ILibrary* getLibrary();
}
```

library.cpp

```
#include "library.h"

#include "business/BCGateway.h"


class LibraryImpl {
public:
    IGateway* getGateway();
};

IGateway* LibraryImpl::getGateway() {
    return BCGateway::instance();
}



ILibrary* Library::instance_ = NULL;
ILibrary* Library::instance() {
    return instance_ ? instance_ : (instance_ = new Library);
}

Library::Library() {
    library_ = new LibraryImpl();
}

Library::~Library() {
    delete library_;
}

IGateway* Library::getGateway() const {
    return library_->getGateway();
}


extern "C" {
    IMPORT_EXPORT
    ILibrary* getLibrary(){
        return Library::instance();
    }
}
```

business/BCGateway.h

```
#include <igateway.h>

class BCGateway: public IGateway {
public:
    static IGateway* instance();

protected:
    BCGateway();

private:
    static IGateway* instance_;
};
```

business/BCGateway.cpp

```
#include "BCGateway.h"

IGateway* BCGateway::instance_ = NULL;
IGateway* BCGateway::instance(){
    return instance_ ? instance_ : (instance_ = new BCGateway);
}
```

I can connect to the library and successfully load the Library-instance. But when I call library->getGateway() in my main-app I get the following error:

> symbol lookup error: ./gateways/libSwisscomXtraZone.so: undefined symbol: _ZN9BCGateway8instanceEv

Can you please give me a hint, how I can resolve this? I'm stuck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I put the error through `c++filt`, it says that the mangled name stands for

```
BCGateway::instance()
```

This suggests that you call `BCGateway::instance()` somewhere and forgot to link against `BCGateway.o` or you even forgot to define `BCGateway::instance()`.

Comment: Written my last comment, I saw, that I just have forgotten to add the BCGateway.h and BCGateway.cpp to my project file, out of which the makefile is generated. So this class was indeed not declared in my library. Since I am very new to c++ libraries, I thought it is an issue with the library declaration or so. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What is this `c+filt` black magic? you just saved my day.

Comment: `c++filt` is part of the GNU binutils: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html

Answer (score 1):

well all static members must be intialised in a cpp file.  Seeing as BCGateway::instance is not intialised at any point it will be unable to find the symbol.  The problem is, however, that if you create a BCGateway.cpp and initialise the instance then you will end up only having one instance across, potentially, many processes.  This may or may not be a problem depending on how you use the DLL.

Comment: Instances will not be shared across processes.  Not even in a shared library.

Comment: All symbols need to be 'defined'.  This one is only 'declared'.  I guess that's what you mean to say. (As opposed to 'initialized')

Comment: well, I just did not add the content of BCGateway.cpp above. I have it in my library. I edited my first post and inserted the missing BCGateway.cpp